# Want to replace dimmer switch with smart switch. I think I have a 3 way dimmer?

Tags: electrical, lighting, led, dimmer-switch, smart-switch

I have a dimmer switch and a regular switch in two different locations. Both control one set of lights.

Is this called a 3 way dimmer switch? The 3 way dimmer switch is the master and the regular switch is the slave?

Would I have to replace both with a smart switch? If so, what would I look for?

I am not familiar with 3 way switches or dimmer switches.

https://ibb.co/DwF151C
https://ibb.co/T81sbYT

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the boxes involved please? Also, what make/model of smart switch are you looking at using, or have you not selected one yet?

Comment: https://ibb.co/DwF151C    https://ibb.co/T81sbYT     No preference for smart switch. I can figure that out myself. Just not sure if I need a 3 way dimmer smart switch which for some comes with another regular smart switch? Or a dimmer smart switch and another smart switch

Comment: A lot of what you need will depend on the brand/model you purchase. I have some smart dimmers that work standalone, _OR_ can work with a smart remote switch, _OR_ can work with a dumb switch. Some will _require_ their own brand of slave switch, some will work with another smart 3-way.